# MySQL query to check if an email has multiple userID's

Tags: mysql

I wanna do a check in my database if there are emails with multiple userID's. I have tried to query below but it just counts the records that's not realy my goal.

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(*), email FROM `userAccountCredential` GROUP BY userID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Let' say there is an email a@a.com with userID 1 and userID 2 I want to get a@a.com as a result so a list of the emails with multiple userID's.

Comment: If you want to know the number of user per email, then why do you group by on the users instead of the emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT email
FROM `userAccountCredential` 
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(distinct userId) > 1
```

Comment: I feel like this checks if there are userID's with multiple emails, I want to get the records (if there are any) that select the emails if a userID has multiple emails. Basically in normal language I want to check if you can make multiple accounts with the same email :p

Comment: This query groups by the email and takes only those groups having more than one record for an email. If you can have more entries for an email but with the same UserID then you can replace `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` with `HAVING COUNT(distinct userId) > 1`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand I am realy confused :p

Comment: My goal is to select all emails that are the same so let's say a@a.a but there is a different userID for example there is a record a@a.a with userID 1 and another record a@a.a with userID 2

Comment: Yes, that is what the query does. Why not just test it?

Comment: I did test it but all emails are unique so it's a bit weird

Comment: That query returns only emails that are present in more than one record. Do you have different records with the same email and the same userID?

Comment: Yes that's possible too

Comment: Then use as I already mentioned `HAVING COUNT(distinct userId) > 1`

Comment: And in the future please add example data and expected output to your question to avoid confusion. It will get you the answers you need much faster.